# Enterprise Redis JSON.GET Syntax for JSONARRAY contains

Tags: arrays, json, redis, enterprise

I'am looking what functionalities that Redis Enterprise can offer, and came up with following questions.
Content in JSON using JSON.Set

```
JSON.SET warehouse:1 $ '{
    "city": "Boston",
    "location": "42.361145, -71.057083",
    "inventory": [
        {   
            "id": 15970,
            "gender": "Men",
            "season":["Fall", "Winter"],
            "description": "Turtle Check Men Navy Blue Shirt",
            "price": 34.95
        },
        {
            "id": 59263,
            "gender": "Women",
            "season": ["Fall", "Winter", "Spring", "Summer"],
            "description": "Titan Women Silver Watch",
            "price": 129.99
        },
        {
            "id": 46885,
            "gender": "Boys",
            "season": ["Fall"],
            "description": "Ben 10 Boys Navy Blue Slippers",
            "price": 45.99
        }
    ]
}'
```

How to write JSON.GET warehouse:1 for "season" contains "Winter"

Comment: Hi there - you'll need to use the search capability for that, and create a search index over the JSON documents you're storing.  That will then allow for full text querying and other SQL like query operations over the JSON documents. https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a "contains" operation for JSONPath. At the moment, I don't believe this is possible. This isn't a limitation with Redis Enterprise or Redis Stack, this is a limitation of JSONPath itself.

I did some googling and found some bits and bobs with proposed syntax for JSONPath to do this. However, nothing implemented yet.

There might be a clever hack to get around this but I couldn't think of one. I would suggest that you check out the [JSONPath docs for Redis](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/path/#jsonpath-syntax), looking specifically at the filtering examples, and that you play around with what you can do with JSONPath with an [online evaluator](https://jsonpath.com/).

Answer (score 0):

- If you know which JSON document to look into, JSONPath filters can be used, as suggested by Guy Royse,
  For example, to get the id of items with `Winter` in season:

  ```
  JSON.GET warehouse:1 '$.inventory[?(@.season[?(@=="Winter")])].id'
  ```
- If you do not know which JSON document to look into, RediSearch can be used, as suggested by Simon Prickett,
  For example:

  ```
  FT.CREATE idx:inventory ON JSON SCHEMA '$.inventory[*].season[*]' AS season TAG
  ```

  And then search for documents

  ```
  FT.SEARCH idx:inventory @season:{Winter}
  ```

  Or also retrieve the relevant id

  ```
  FT.SEARCH idx:inventory @season:{Winter} RETURN 1 '$.inventory[?(@.season[?(@=="Winter")])].id'
  ```